# Missing dictionaries for spell-checking with kate and kile

Tags: unity, 14.10, kate, spell-checking, kile

Spell-checking works in Kate and Kile, but only for English texts. It is not possible to select another language and dictionary.

The selection of the dict is available for Kate/Kile at:
Settings -> Configure Kate/Kile... -> Editor Component -> Editing

The Editing Options contains a tab named "Spellcheck". At the top is a drop down menu named "Default language". The menu is nearly empty. It contains two entries one blank and ellipse "()".

Starting Kate from the command line shows many messages:
Enchant dict for "en"

Selecting the "()" as default language exchanges the "en" with "en_ZA".

I installed systemsettings from KDE (I am using ubuntu-desktop/unity). Selecting Locale -> Spell Checker contains the same drop down menu as it is available from Kate and Kile.

I suppose that the problem was introduced during one many upgrades in the past. I installed the system some years ago ...

Any ideas how I get a German language and dictionary?

Using gedit the German dict is selectable.

These are my installed dictionaries/language packages:

```
ii  aspell-de                20120607-1                        all   German dictionary for aspell
ii  hunspell-de-de           20120607-1                        all   German dictionary for hunspell
ii  hyphen-de                1:3.3.0-2ubuntu3                  all   German hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org
ii  kde-l10n-de              4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1               all   German (de) localization for KDE
ii  language-pack-de         1:13.10+20131012                  all   translation updates for language German
ii  language-pack-gnome-de   1:13.10+20131012                  all   GNOME translation updates for language German
```

System is an up-to-date Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, 64-bit. I am still facing this problem after update to 14.04 Trusty. This is still true on 14.10 Utopic.

Any ideas about how to get the German dictionary into Kate?

Answer (score 11):

Just install for example `hunspell-de-de package`, restart Kate and you should be good to go, German added to spelling dictionaries.

```
sudo apt-get install hunspell-de-de
```

I used muon package manager myself.

Comment: As shown in my question `hunspell-de-de` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used KDE in years, but is it conceivable that the options are buried somewhere in **System Settings -> Regional & Language**?

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right. There is a tab named "Country/Region & Language". I checked the the tab named language. But this language setting influences the localization of the applications and not the used dictionary for spell-checking. My System Settings are now called "Systemeinstellungen". The selection of a German dictionary is still not possible.
One additional remark: I am not using KDE, only some really good  apps from KDE. I tried the Gnome equivalent to Kile named Gummi. It has a working spell-checker but crashes nearly immediately when opening a 20 pages document 8-(

Comment: Systemeinstellungen sounds familiar ;) Too bad I could be more helpful :-\